# Way to add pytest options outside top level conftest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a project that defines testing support modules, including py.test plugins in a package subdirectory like this:

```
bokeh/_testing
├── __init__.py
├── plugins
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── bokeh_server.py
│   ├── examples_report.jinja
│   ├── examples_report.py
│   ├── file_server.py
│   ├── implicit_mark.py
│   ├── integration_tests.py
│   ├── jupyter_notebook.py
│   ├── log_file.py
│   └── pandas.py
└── util
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── api.py
    ├── examples.py
    ├── filesystem.py
    ├── git.py
    └── travis.py
```

Several of the plugins need to define new options with `parser.addoption`. I would like these calls to be made inside the respective plugin modules. However, if I do that, and include those plugins in a test file with, e.g.

```
# test_examples.py
pytest_plugins = (
    "bokeh.testing.plugins.bokeh_server",
    "bokeh.testing.plugins.examples_report",
)

# pytest.mark.examples test code here
```

Then pytest complains that any custom command line options are undefined:

```
(base) ❯ py.test -s -v -m examples --diff-ref FETCH_HEAD --report-path=examples.html
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --diff-ref --report-path=examples.html
  inifile: /Users/bryanv/work/bokeh/setup.cfg
  rootdir: /Users/bryanv/work/bokeh
```

The only way I have found around this, is to collect ***ALL*** custom options in a single `pytest_addoption` in the top-level `conftest.py`:

```
# conftest.py
pytest_plugins = (
    "bokeh.testing.plugins.implicit_mark",
    "bokeh.testing.plugins.pandas",
)

# Unfortunately these seem to all need to be centrally defined at the top level
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--upload", dest="upload", action="store_true", default=False, help="..."
    )

    # ... ALL other addoptions calls for all plugins here ...
```

As I said, this works, but is very inflexible in terms of code organization. It would be preferable to have a way for the options for the `examples.py` plugin to *in* the `examples.py` module, with the code it relates to.

Another possibility would presumably be to bring in all the plugins in the top-level `conftest.py`, but some of the plugins are very heavyweight, e.g. depend on Selenium, and I would not like to require that all that be installed just to run basic tests.

Is there another way to accomplish this, and if so, how?

Comment: [As stated in the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption): _This function should be implemented only in plugins or `conftest.py` files situated at the tests root directory due to how pytest discovers plugins during startup._ You will have to move the `addoption` hooks to root `conftest` or a plugin loaded from `conftest`, which is essentially the same.

Comment: I guess this kinda makes sense if the test collection filters should be readable from command line args - to know which test modules should be skipped, the args should be already parsed, so the arg parsing occurs before test dir traversal, test module loading and test collection.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that docs page, I was scouring the [Writing Plugins](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html) documentation and there was nothing specifically relevant there. Still, that's unfortunate, for the reasons above. if you'd like to add this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Let me think about it for a while, I guess it could be possible to implement some kind of second-tier arg parsing and configuration, including the hooks from collected test modules. The question is how much monkey patching it will require and whether the solution will be stable enough.

Comment: Sure, for my immediate situation I was thinking of storing the `addoption` args near the plugins in some simple format, and having the `__init__` for the plugins directory automatically collect them. Then the `conftest.py` can import `bokeh._testing.plugins.opts` and iterate over it in a top-level `pytest_addoption` call. But I'd be happy to scrap that eventually for a supported solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, as of Pytest `3.6.2`, options must be added *"only in plugins or conftest.py files situated at the tests root directory due to how pytest discovers plugins during startup."*